# The perfect regex to extract a particular string in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file `abc.txt` that looks like this:

```
dQdC(sA1B2C3,sC5) = A lot of stuff
a = b = c
Baseball
dQdC(sC2V3X1,sD5) = A lot of stuff again
```

Now I want create two arrays in perl, one of which will contain `A1B2C3` and `C2V3X1`, the other array will contain `C5` and `D5`. I don't care about the other intermediate lines. To achieve this goal, I am trying this perl script:

```
for (my $in=0;$in<=$#lines;$in++){
if ($lines[$in]=~/dQdC\(s([A-Z0-9]+?),s([A-Z0-9]+?)\)/) {
  print "1111"; #this line is just to check if it is at all going inside the loop
  @A = $1;
  @B = $2;
}
```

However, it is not even going inside the loop. So I guess I did something wrong with the regex. Will someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can't help it ... are you really after a "_perfect_" regex? :)  I heard that it may be unattainable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my (@a, @b);
while ($file =~ /^dQdC\(s(\w+),s(\w+)\)/mg) {
   push @a, $1;
   push @b, $2;
}
```

or

```
my (@a, @b);
while (<$fh>) {
   if (/^dQdC\(s(\w+),s(\w+)\)/) {
      push @a, $1;
      push @b, $2;
   }
}
```

---

Working with parallel arrays isn't nice.

Alternative 1: Hash

```
my %hash = $file =~ /^dQdC\(s(\w+),s(\w+)\)/mg;
```

or

```
my %hash;
while (<$fh>) {
   if (/^dQdC\(s(\w+),s(\w+)\)/) {
      $hash{$1} = $2;
   }
}
```

Alternative 2: AoA

```
use List::Util qw( pairs );  # 1.29+

my @pairs = pairs( $file =~ /^dQdC\(s(\w+),s(\w+)\)/mg );
```

or

```
my @pairs;
while (<$fh>) {
   if (/^dQdC\(s(\w+),s(\w+)\)/) {
      push @pairs, [ $1, $2 ];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the format of your target lines is always as shown

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = ...

my (@ary_1, @ary_2);

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (<$fh>)
{   
    my ($v1, $v2) = /dQdC\(s([^,]+),s([^\)]+)/ or next;

    push @ary_1, $v1;
    push @ary_2, $v2;
}
```

which captures between `(` and a `,` and then between a `,` and `)`. The first pattern might as well be `s(.*?),` as there is no benefit of the negated character class since the following `,` still need be matched (but I left it with `[^...]` for consistency with the other one).

Comments

- In general better process a file line-by-line, unless there are specific reasons to read it first
- C-style loop is rarely needed. To iterate over array index use `for my $i (0..$#ary)`
- Please `use warnings;` and `use strict;` always

Comment: @ikegami Right, was just testing ... can never be sure whether the second assigned var can escape that ... thank you!

Comment: List assigment in scalar context returns number of elements returned by RHS (`2` on match, `0` on no match).

Comment: @ikegami OK, that makes sense, thank you. Which only leaves it up to the pattern not to "match" some nonsense (like empty) ... and thank you for edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/UK0WLW/1):

```
(?<=\(s)([A-Z0-9]+)(?=,)
```

It matches substrings that come between `(s` and `,` using lookbehind and lookahead.
Similarily, use `(?<=,s)([A-Z0-9]+)(?=\))` to capture the substrings between `,s` and `)`.

[Putting them together](https://regex101.com/r/UK0WLW/2), you can create two capturing groups, each containing the different kind of substrings: `(A1B2C3, C2V3X1), (C5, D5)`